# React Native Fatal RCTBatchedBridge error on launch

Tags: react-native

When lauching the app it fails with the following fatal error:

```
TypeError: methods.forEach is not a function. (In 'methods.forEach', 'methods.forEach' is undefined)
```

This only happens in the iOS simulator. The app runs fine on a device.

The RN stack trace doesn't show much useful information:
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lceNK.png)

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!